# Displaying multiple strings from Python Script output with PHP

Tags: php, python, string

I am currently trying to create a .php file that displays the output of a python file. Here is what I have so far (that semi works).

test.php

```
<?php

    echo "Results from wordgame.py...";
    echo "</br>";
    $output = exec('python wordgame.py cat dog');
    echo $output;

;?>
```

Here is what test.php returns...

```
Results from test.py...
dog
```

Here is the output from 'wordgame.py cat dog' I get when running it from the command line:

```
Generated: 2454
Expanded: 83
Revisited: 0
Path:
        dog
        cog
        cag
        cat
```

My question is, how do I get test.php to print out the same thing it prints at the command line? wordgame.py doesn't "return" anything, it just prints the lines once it's found a path between the words. Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of *exec*, have a look at [*passthru*](http://php.net/passthru). This function has no return value, but will `echo` the entire output of your python script directly to the browser.

```
echo "Results from wordgame.py...<br/>";
passthru('python wordgame.py cat dog');
```

---

Because you have `<br/>` in your original post, you may need to escape the python output and wrap it in a `<pre/>` tag to get the output formatted well for the browser. The easiest way to do this would be with php output buffering.

```
echo "Results from wordgame.py...<br/>";
ob_start();
passthru('python wordgame.py cat dog');
echo "<pre>" . htmlspecialchars(ob_get_clean()) . "</pre>";
```

This will work as long as *wordgame* has relatively short output. If not, you'll need to use a more elaborate solution involving [*proc_open*](http://php.net/proc_open) on the PHP side, or make sure your python code is outputting escaped HTML.

Comment: Thank you for this resource. I have replaced exec with passthru and it works! I will accept this as the answer shortly.